# Auth0. How to get user's permissions and role?

Tags: authentication, authorization, auth0

I am using free plan of Auth0. I've read a ton of different manuals and can't understand, how to get user's permissions. I've set roles, added permissions to them, assigned this role to user. I am using 05-Token-Renewal (from Auth0 examples) and in idTokenPayload I have even picture, but there is no permissions. How to get them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728272/auth0-how-to-get-users-permissions-in-access-token

Comment: Check out this guide to get a user role on Auth0 https://io.permit.io/auth0-integration

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the permission is indirectly related to User through Role. We get the role of user, then collect the permission of this role. It can be reached your goal.
If you are fine with my proposal, we may take a look at the API document from Auth0, following detail:

1. Get the role of user: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/#!/Users/get_user_roles
2. Collect the permission granted by role: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/#!/Roles/get_role_permission

Hope it can help.