# Auth0. How to get user's permissions in access token?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

How to get user's permissions in access token using Auth0's Core Authorization Feature (in very first authorize request)? I need array of all permissions along with another information about user.

P.S. I've created role, permissions, assigned role to user.
Enabled Add Permissions in the Access Token toggle and RBAC in API settings.

Answer (score 4):

It was not obvious in any of the documentation but adding the "audience" parameter like so made it so a permissions array for the API (in my case "settings") is returned.

```
      <Auth0Provider
        domain={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN}
        client_id={process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
        redirect_uri={window.location.origin}
        audience={'settings'}
        onRedirectCallback={appState => {
          window.history.replaceState(
            {},
            document.title,
            appState && appState.targetUrl
              ? appState.targetUrl
              : window.location.pathname
          )
        }}
      >
        {app}
      </Auth0Provider>
```

```
  "permissions": [
    "create:settings",
    "read:settings",
    "update:settings"
  ]
```

I then wanted to request permissions for multiple audiences (logical APIs in my case) but currently you can only pass a single audience.

The recommendation is to create a single logical API and put all the permissions under that API and then use that as the "audience" to pull back  all the permissions.

Reference: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/represent-multiple-apis